# Have application menu open up with only Windows/Super key

Tags: release-freya, slingshot

Is there anyway to open up the applications menu with only the windows key, and not the Windows+Space Bar?

Comment: Please select this bug  affects you: https://bugs.launchpad.net/switchboard-plug-keyboard/+bug/1333015

Comment: I usually use spotlight to launch application faster, http://www.webupd8.org/2015/01/albert-fast-lightweight-quick-launcher.html

Comment: I really like this but it was causing Firefox several issue. It was very irritating because at first I didn't realize this tweak was causing it. I just thought the new Elementary was buggy with Firefox, or visa versa. After extensive testing and troubleshooting, I finally realized that maybe this shortcut tweak may have cause it. After finding out the command to disable it, all issues with Firefox went away. - Issue 1. Scrolling wheel on my mouse would zoom in/out about 50% of the time. - Issue 2. Right clicking on highlighted text would select-all text on page. - Issue 3. Right clicking menu

Answer (score 37):

You can assign <kbd>Super</kbd> key to open Slingshot-launcher on **Loki** with following commands:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.mutter overlay-key "'Super_L'"
gsettings set org.pantheon.desktop.gala.behavior overlay-action "'wingpanel --toggle-indicator=app-launcher'"
```

Comment: how can I undo this? I cannot use any shortcut with combination of winkey now (found it myself : dconf reset /org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings/panel-main-menu )

Comment: @Woeitg You can reset this with `gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings panel-main-menu`

Comment: I tried on 0.3.2. The shortcut worked, but when the panel menu is up and I switch to another workspace, (not the one w/ panel menu up) then I cannot use <super>+Num to switch any other workspaces. (I guess I just cannot use any combination with <super> as modifier)

Comment: You deserve a cookie @png2378

Comment: I see no reason why this isn't the default behavior. Is there an issue tracker for this?

Comment: Looks like they fixed the bug where you can't use combinations of winkey now (Fresh install of Juno)

Answer (score 21):

This currently can be configured from `System Settings -> Keyboard` like

[image]

Comment: this should be higher up, this is exactly what OP needed

Comment: This is the right answer.

Comment: Indeed - this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 5):

You can't do that through the custom shortcuts that you can set via Switchboard, which only allow combinations of 2 or more keystrokes.

I believe it is possible using [xbindkeys](http://man.cx/xbindkeys%281%29), though. 
To install it (along with a GUI configurator) paste this command into a terminal window:

```
sudo apt-get install xbindkeys-config
```

In order to run, the program needs a config file in your home directory. Create it with this command:

```
xbindkeys --defaults > /home/YOURUSERNAME/.xbindkeysrc
```

Now run the program by typing `xbindkeys-config` into the terminal or in the search string of the application launcher. This window will fire up:

[image]

Hit "New" to create your custom command. On the top right box you must type in all relevant information: a name for the shortcut, the key assigned to it, and the command to execute the program (in your case `slingshot-launcher`). To get the name of the correct key use the "Get Key" button. A blank window will pop up. Just press your key and the program will automatically record its name code. Hit "Save & Apply & Exit" and you're done.

Now the bad news: in my test I couldn't assign the Super key. I'm afraid it is already binded to other shortcuts, but I couldn't troubleshoot the issue. I was able to assign a "less-used" key, though, like the "Pause" key.

*Note*. To make this setup permanent you need to add `xbindkeys` to your startup applications.

Comment: This post is a super long comment to saintjules' response. This is a post, not a comment, because I cannot comment yet. You can assign the meta (super, windows logo, command, Mod4) key to slingshot-launcher. Here's how: 1. Assuming you have completed saintjules' response, open a terminal. Type `xmodmap -pke | grep '= Super_L NoSymbol Super_L'`. 2. Make note of the keycode number. 3. Run `xbindkeys-config`. 4. Create the item according to saintjules' response, but in the "Key: " field, type `Super_L | c:your_keycode_number`. For me, this would be `Super_L | c:133`.
Now you should be able to pre

Comment: "... press meta to open the launcher."

Comment: Good catch, Merlin04! It's not clear if you can post answers or not, so I'll ask the mods: should I just edit my answer?