# how to undo keyboard shortcut (Win key launch Applications)

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

I have set up a keyboard shortcut using the helpful answers at [Have application menu open up with only Windows key](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1946/have-application-menu-open-up-with-only-windows-key) which opens my Applications dock when I use Windows key. However, this is now interfering with other shortcuts.

Is there a way to remove this keyboard shortcut?

I don't remember which method I used, it was one of the answers in question above, is there a way to check which method I used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `System Settings` > `Keyboard`. Then select `Applications` from the left menu. From the list on the right, change the shortcut of the `Applications Launcher` by clicking on it and pressing Super key and Space(the default shortcut). You need to re-login for the shortcut to take effect.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I had no idea this keyboard shortcut thing existed in Settings! elementary is great OS, lol.

Comment: Happy to help :)