# Super Key only for window overview - elementaryOS

Tags: release-loki, wingpanel, slingshot

Is there any way to configure <kbd>SUPER</kbd> (aka <kbd>WINKEY</kbd>) to launch window overview, like in Gnome?

I already tried the commands below for app launcher and it works.

```
settings set org.gnome.mutter overlay-key "'Super_L'"
gsettings set org.pantheon.desktop.gala.behavior overlay-action "'wingpanel --toggle-indicator=app-launcher'"
```

from here: [Have application menu open up with only Windows/Super key](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1946/have-application-menu-open-up-with-only-windows-key)

But, what would be the command to replace "app-launcher" by "window overview"?

Answer (score 2):

You got the first part right, the name of the command for overview according to [this post](http://eos-snippets.blogspot.com/2014/09/terminal-commands-to-initiate-gala.html) is:

`dbus-send --session --dest=org.pantheon.gala --print-reply /org/pantheon/gala org.pantheon.gala.PerformAction int32:1`

Simply replace your second command with the action like so:

`gsettings set org.pantheon.desktop.gala.behavior overlay-action "'dbus-send --session --dest=org.pantheon.gala --print-reply /org/pantheon/gala org.pantheon.gala.PerformAction int32:1'"`