# Super Key = Overview of all Windows - but its not closing on second press

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

I've found multiple guides (e.g. [this](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/13116/super-key-only-for-window-overview-elementaryos)) detailing how to map the "Overview of all windows" onto the Super key. I've used following approach:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.mutter overlay-key "'Super_L'"
gsettings set org.pantheon.desktop.gala.behavior overlay-action "'xdotool key super+w'"
```

But when I have the window overview open, then I can't close it again with the Super key.

This is unlike the behaviour of the actual keyboard command (super+w) which opens the overview on the first tap and closes on the second.

How can I achieve this functionality on ONLY the super key?

Answer (score 0):

I was fighting with this a lot of time and at the end I have failed...

For some reason elementay OS do not allow using the Super key for this purpose and if you manage to achieve such a functionality it is like a hack and always has some downsides.

For example I use the *Super key* now to show applications menu and works without any problems because there is such a setting into

*System settings > Keyboard > Layout*

But when I was trying to remap it with `xdotool` or another 'solutions' I have found ... some of the native shortcuts has gone or the opening of the multitasking view did not work flowlessly - sometimes it opens, sometimes has to press it twice to open and sometimes is like your case - cannot return from multitasking when I press the Super key for a second time.

Wish you good luck, if you find a solution, will be happy to try it.